# Jquery to validate the selection in dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I have following drop down list code, which I am trying to validate for selection. I am getting the length 0 in all cases. How can I check if an option is selected?

```
<select name="handpick"  size="10" multiple>
<option value="25248739">New York
<option value="25248716">California
</select>



var handpickselector = $('select[name="handpick"]');
        if ($("handpickselector option:selected").length <= 0){

            //show error message

            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. Since it's been wrapped in `""`, JS is treating `handpickselector` as part of the string itself. Just update as follows:

```
if( handpickselector.find('option:selected').length == 0 )
```

Notice we also do an exact comparison (i.e. `==`), since a jQuery collection cannot have a length `< 0`.